# PDF generated by JasperReports: right portion cuts in browser

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports

I am working with *JasperReports*. The PDF is working fine in my machine but, it looks the right end cut in some other system (in Mozilla-in client system as well), ie last column is rendered half, not completely. I searched a lot, but didn't get any related post. Have anyone noticed such a problem? Any help will be [image]greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot? Did you check the generated file in a *pdf* viewer, for example in *Adobe Reader*? Is it ok?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I have edited and added a screenshot in question.I think  it's a browser issue and it doesn't happen with all systems.The PDF is generated and shown in browser there the problem exists.It 's working fine in ireport and pdf viewer.Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a very old question but for anyone having similar issue please add this property to your report:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.size.page.to.content" value="true"/>
```

[image]